# Synology DS218+ NAS new folder can not be seen from remote log in

Tags: network-attached-storage, remote, synology

I am getting some odd behaviour on my client's NAS, a **Synology DS218+** the TLDR is that it's not letting me see a *new* folder from remote. The DS218+ is a machine that is new to me, and I'm learning that it's not set up exactly like a typical server, though it mimics many of these features.

This happened after I **tried to create a new shared folder** (called "Staff Files") and updated an existing user's permissions so that they see the folder. The user's permissions should be read-only and they should not be able to access the rest of the NAS drive.

Folder permissions are thus:

[image: Staff Files folder permissions]

And the user permissions are thus:

[image: -staff- user permissions]

A Mac workstation **logging in with the Synology Drive Client gets the message** "Testing connection…", followed by "Checking username and password…" which is immediately followed by:

> **No shared folder available to establish the task.** Please go to the Synology Drive Admin Console to enable the shared folders you would like to connect to or contact the system administrator.

An **iPhone logging in as "staff" simply goes to an empty "Team Folders".**

To me, it seems like **the folder is created on the server (NAS), but not mapped to the WAN connection.** This theory is supported when I log in as an "office" user (with read/write privileges on all three folders, I see only the two existing folders:

[image: mapping screen showing only the two already-existing files]

I'm somewhat familiar with establishing remote service, as I have set up and currently maintain a LAMP server start-to-finish, top-to-bottom.

**What the devil am I missing here!?!**

It should be noted that the two existing folders are working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for some time, I smashed a hole through it.

It's not intuitive, so I'll include it here, for the edification of future generations.

Opening the "Package Manager" in the admin portal allows you to see all *installed* packages:

[image: image of Synology Drive Package manager]

Note and click on the Synology Drive Server:

[image: detail image showing the Synology Drive Server icoon]

This is the only way I found to access the GUI for the "Synology Drive Admin Console" where one can select "Team Folder" from the left-of-screen menu.

The Team Folder details clearly show us the full list of folders and the status of each. Note that my renegade folder is described as "Not Enabled":

[image: Team Folder details showing us the full list of folders and the status of each]

Clicking the "Enable" action button gave me all of the needed actions to enable the folder for sync.

Hoping this helps you.